# How to import ddd mmm dd 00:00:00 zzz yyyy as dd-MMM-yyyy in mysql database using Struts2

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to import data from excel to MySQL using Struts2. Here I imported all data, but I got problem with date. This excel has a column as month(Apr-2014).

I imported that Month columns also in database. But whenever I retrieved with Month field it shows data like first Apr-2014, Aug-2014, Jul-2014, Jan-2014. Actually, my database has total (Apr-2014 to Apr-2015) 1 year data. Each month has 440 records.

I created J.S.P page for retrieving data using months between.

MySQL database:

```
 ______________________________________________________________________
 | ATM_Site_No  |    L H O     |   Revenue   |Up_Time|   Month        |
 |______________|______________|_____________|_______|________________|
 |S1OZ000262004 |    KERALA    |   42,371    |96.85% |   Apr-2014     |
 |S1OZ000266006 |   HYDERABAD  |   28,572    |95.61% |   Apr-2014     |
 |S1OZ000327005 |   BHOPAL     |   43,812    |99.32% |   Apr-2014     |
 |______________|______________|_____________|_______|________________|
 |S1OZ000262004 |    KERALA    |   41,659    |92.18% |   May-2014     |
 |S1OZ000266006 |   HYDERABAD  |   28,572    |95.61% |   May-2014     |
 |S1OZ000327005 |   BHOPAL     |   43,812    |99.32% |   May-2014     |
 |______________|______________|_____________|_______|________________|
 |S1OZ000262004 |    KERALA    |   42,371    |96.85% |   Jun-2014     |
 |S1OZ000266006 |   HYDERABAD  |   41,659    |92.18% |   Jun-2014     |
 |S1OZ000327005 |   BHOPAL     |   43,812    |99.32% |   Jun-2014     |
 |______________|______________|_____________|_______|________________|
```

Retrieve.jsp:

```
<s:form action="uptimeview.action" method="post">
    <s:select name="LHO" lable="LHO" list="{'KERALA','HYDERABAD', 'BHOPAL','ALL'}"/>

    <sx:datetimepicker name="fromMonth" lable="From Month" displayFormate="dd-MMM-yyyy"/>

    <sx:datetimepicker name="toMonth"   lable="To Month" displayFormate="dd-MMM-yyyy"/>

    <s:submit value="submit" align="center"></s:submit>        
</s:form>
```

ViewUpTimeAction.java:

```
     package com.cedge.action;
     import java.sql.Connection;
     import java.sql.ResultSet;
     import java.sql.Statement;
     import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.List;
     import javax.naming.Context;
     import javax.naming.InitialContext;
     import javax.sql.DataSource;
     import com.cedge.bean.UpTimeBean;
     import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

     public class ViewUpTimeAction extends ActionSupport{

          private String LHO;
          private Date fromMonth;
          private Date toMonth;

          public String getLHO() {
               return LHO;
                                 }
          public void setLHO(String LHO) {
               this.LHO = LHO;
                                         }
          public Date getFromMonth() {
               return fromMonth;
                                     }
          public void setFromMonth(Date fromMonth) {
               this.fromMonth = fromMonth;
                                                   }
          public Date getToMonth() {
               return toMonth;
                                   }
          public void setToMonth(Date toMonth) {
               this.toMonth = toMonth;
                                               }
       private List<UpTimeBean> uptimeBeans=new ArrayList<UpTimeBean>();
          public List<UpTimeBean> getUptimeBeans() {
               return uptimeBeans;
                                                   }
          public void setUptimeBeans(List<UpTimeBean> uptimeBeans) {
               this.uptimeBeans = uptimeBeans;
                                                                   }
          public String execute() throws NullPointerException{
               System.out.println(fromMonth);
               System.out.println(toMonth);
               System.out.println(LHO);

   impleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
          String fMonth=simpleDateFormat.format(fromMonth);
          System.out.println(fMonth);
          String tMonth=simpleDateFormat.format(toMonth);
          System.out.println(tMonth);

          String ret=ERROR;
          try{
          Context initCtx=new InitialContext();
          Context envCtx=(Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
          DataSource ds=(DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/myTest");
          Connection connection=ds.getConnection();
          Statement statement=connection.createStatement();

          ResultSet resultSet=null;
          switch(LHO){
          case "ALL": resultSet=statement.executeQuery
          ("SELECT * FROM revenue WHERE Month BETWEEN '"+fMonth+"'
          AND '"+tMonth+"' ORDER BY Month");

          break;

          default: resultSet=statement.executeQuery(
          "SELECT * FROM revenue WHERE LHO='"+LHO+"' and Month BETWEEN
          '"+fMonth+"' AND '"+tMonth+"' ORDER BY Month");

           }
          while(resultSet.next()){
          UpTimeBean fileBean=new UpTimeBean();
          fileBean.setATM_Site_No(resultSet.getString(1));
          fileBean.setATM_Location(resultSet.getString(2));
          fileBean.setLHO(resultSet.getString(3));
          fileBean.setCash(resultSet.getDouble(4));
          fileBean.setNon_Cash(resultSet.getDouble(5));
          fileBean.setRevenue(resultSet.getDouble(6));
          fileBean.setUp_Time(resultSet.getString(7));
          fileBean.setMonth(resultSet.getString(8));
          System.out.println("fileBean"+fileBean);
          uptimeBeans.add(fileBean);
          System.out.println(uptimeBeans);
          }
          return SUCCESS;
          }catch(Exception exception){
              System.out.println(exception);
              ret=ERROR;
                                     }
              return ret;
          }
          }
```

Here I tried to retrieve data between Months. I tried to retrieve 
data between `Apr-2014` and `Jun-2014`. But, I got data like `Apr-2014`
`Aug-2014`, `Jul-2014`, and `Jun-2014`. I need data should be
like this `Apr-2014`, `May-2014`, and `Jun-2014`.
Please help me to get data from MySQL between Months.

Comment: Change the data format to timestamp.